# How to get data from Future<String> in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have an issue with future in dart, i'm trying to get data from it

```
  Future getCategories() async {
    http
        .post(
        Uri.parse('https://someurlblahblah'),
        body: "{\"token\": \"admintesttoken\"}",
        headers: headers)
        .then((response) {
      print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');
      return response.body;
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("Error: $error");
      return error;
    });
  }
```

here is the code example, here i'm trying to get data from it

```
  getCategories() async {
  String asdasd = await Server().getCategories();
  print(asdasd);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: it returns "null" everytime, it returns it before server response

Comment: What is the response from the POST request exactly? Have you tried to call this endpoint independently from Flutter, for example with Postman? Is it a string, a JSON etc.?

Comment: You also have to wait for the POST result in your async function, like `final response = await http.post...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything inside your `getCategories` function, therefore it's implicitely returning null:

```
Future<String> getCategories() async {
  // Add a `return` clause here (the `await` is optional):
  return await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://someurlblahblah'),
    body: "{\"token\": \"admintesttoken\"}",
    headers: headers,
  ).then((response) {
    print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response body: ${response.body}');
    return response.body;
  }).catchError((error) {
    print("Error: $error");
    return error;
  });
}
```